# In Java API documentation, what does it mean to inherit an abstract method?

Tags: java, documentation, inheritance

Here's an example: In the [documentation for java.util.HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), there's a list of "Methods inherited from interface java.util.Set", including equals, which is an abstract method in java.util.Set. In contrast, other abstract methods in java.util.Set have their own documentation in java.util.HashSet, such as [`iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#iterator). Why the difference?

Comment: Is your question about the language or about how Java API is documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashSet has an **explicit** implementation for `iterator`:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
}
```

so that method appears in the first section of the method summary.

It does *not* explicitly implement `equals`; it uses the implementation of its base class `AbstractSet`. Note that `equals` appears in both "Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractSet" and "Methods inherited from interface java.util.Set". `equals` is an abstract method in the interface `Set` but not in the (abstract) class `AbstractSet`.